# UserId does not exist php file structure

Tags: php, phpunit

I am working on writing my phpunit tests and when I run them I get this error:
**Class or interface "UserId" does not exist
/Users/alexvannorsdall/code/InterestAccount/Tests/Unit/Application/Commands/UserTest.php:29**

What I am writing is pretty basic so I am unsure of why it can't find the appropriate class it is testing. This is my file structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDvYm.png)

I have looked into my namespace. Looked at my composer.json which is this:

```
{
    "name": "alexvannorsdall/interest-account",
    "require": {
        "ramsey/uuid": "^4.7",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Alexvannorsdall\\InterestAccount\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Alexandria Vannorsdall",
            "email": "arvannorsdall@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also looked at documentation with no luck.

Comment: Here is top of my UserId test: 

*namespace Unit\Application\Commands;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Exception;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use RuntimeException;
use User;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use UserId;*

Comment: Better [edit] that into your question then commenting. That part is important.

Comment: And also that part from the UserId.php for the UserId class you're looking for. In the end it's `use UserId;` that is wrong if you compare it with the fully qualified class name of UserId, it is in a namespace. Change to `use <the-class-namespace>\UserId;` and your code should fly. You can find this detailed in the PHP manual [Using namespaces: Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) and for `use` in [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)